# how to extract up to the minute component of a unix timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a list of POSIX timestamps such as `1331567982` that I process using [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) which gives me a date format like: `year - month - day - hour - minute - seconds`.

However, for resampling purposes I just need to extract the timestamp up to the minute precision, that is `year - month - day - hour - minute`, but no seconds.

How can I do that using functions from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module only (no [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) function:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1331567982)
d.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```